# Parent-Child relation in solr

Tags: solr

I'm using SOLR 4.10 to index fields from 3 tables(Item, Item_Detail, Order) where two tables(Item_Detail and Order) are child of Item with one-to-many relationship.
How can I index all the three, so that I can get parent and child entities in one query.

For E.x If I query with some value from Item entity, I should retrieve the Item_Detail and Order values associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have to declare all of your fields that you will need for any of the records in your schema.xml (or use dynamic fields).  Additionally, you probably want to add a field called "content-type" or something like that, which will allow you to set whether it is a parent record or a child record.  You could set the values to things like "item," "item_detail," and "order."  From there, you will use a Block Join Query.  See [Solr Other Parsers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers) for more information, along with syntax details.

As a note, all of your documents will be intermixed, so that if you run a normal query, like q=*: *, then you will get back all of your results.  This is when your content-type field is handy, as you can do q=content-type:item to only get parent records.